# A problem in time line rendering of server/client controls with javascript, jQuery and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two text boxes (select) which I want to change the contents of the second according to the selection of the first. I draw them with jQuery functions and handle the event like that as well. But I think I am mistaken to handle the event of changed selected index of the first one by jQuery because the page would have already been loaded. So any suggestions how to solve that out?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+cascading+select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you mean, but if you want your second drop-down be populated depending on the first one by the time the page loads, you either populate it with PHP when dynamically creating a page, or you could trigger changed event with jquery like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#yuourfirstdropdown').change(function() {
    // your code here
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's what I want. I am also using ajax which return xml result called from jQuery. Is it possible to use that as well, because the whole system is built this way so I would prefer to walk on the same path?

Comment: depends on how you want your system to work. i myself prefer creating the whole page when loading, this way it is fast on a slower connection and user doesn't have to wait till all ajax requests are made to see the page. but i don't really know your case, so i can't advise anything

Answer (score 0):

You want to have change event on second drop down populated from the first change function. If that's your requirement, use live function.

```
$('select.changeddropdown').live('change',function(){
   //code here 
})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more details on live function

Comment: I use it. But for some reason, nothing happen when the selection changes. The event is fired, but the second listbox doesn't change.